# Configuring a Ruby Project to use gems outside of a Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

From my understanding (And from what I've seen by using this) if a project has a Gemfile, it only has access to gems that are in the Gemfile (Or more specifically, the Gemfile.lock file).

I want to be able to use some gems that are installed on the system, but not particularly in the Gemfile.lock file - How would I go about this?

For my reasoning: We have a developer VM setup that ensures everything is up to date; however without running `bundle update` within the project, a tool that we use (That relies on a Gem) cannot be updated (Or even used, if it isn't in the Gemfile).

I can keep the gem updated, but cannot force the project to use the version without updating the Gemfile.lock information - So I would prefer to just let the project use all or specific system gems, and just have the Gemfile as a "quick way to get your system up to date with the project".

Another note: The application uses rake tasks to operate (Tool has a gem, the gem looks for a specific rake file for custom configuration).

Answer (score 1):

where are your system gems installed?

make sure to have `GEM_PATH` env var set to that location.

use `gem env gempath` to check you have it set correctly.

if not, set it in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

```
export GEM_PATH='/path/to/system/gems'
```

Comment: This is on a per-project basis. It will work fine for projects that do not have a Gemfile. It's a Gemfile "feature" that you're limited to the gems within the Gemfile in that project. I'll give this a try, but what you're alluding to seems like it wouldn't work. I can use my gems anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to require the library (read gem).

You can require it in a specific file that uses the gem's functionality, or you can require it in `config/application.rb` (in Rails 3) to make it available to the whole app.

To be safe, ensure that the gem is available:

```
if Gem::Specification::find_by_name('my_gem')
  require 'my_gem'
end
```

Comment: Hm, no luck. I'm running Rails 3.2.6 - It's now saying "Could not find *gem name* (>= 0) and lists all the gems that were installed with Bundler, but not all the gems on the system as the gem is installed when I check with gem list. Updated my question on the last line with a bit of extra info. Also added a require in the Rakefile.